# General form for the rotation of a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

When rotating linear functions, I would approach the task geometrically (find invariant point etc.), yet I tried using a matrix which worked nicely.

This was what I did to rotate $y=2x+1$ by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ about the origin.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 2x+1\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1-x\\ 3x+1
\end{pmatrix},$$

$$x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-x)\; ,\; y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(3x+1).$$

So,
$$y'=2\sqrt{2}-3x'.$$

I have also tried this on non-linear functions and it worked.

When I try to generalize this, I obtain:

$$x'=x\cos(\theta )-y\sin(\theta)\; ,\; y'=x\cos(\theta )+y\sin(\theta).$$

The problem is I can only seem to eliminate one of either $x$ or $y$. Is it possible to eliminate both?

Other related questions I have are:

- Can you use matrices to rotate a function around an arbitrary point, not the origin?
- Can this concept by applied to 3-dimensions? What about parametric functions?
- Can anyone recommend any material for pursing matrix transformations of functions (possibly of more than one variable)?

For reference, I am currently a secondary school student in the UK.

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to your question about rotating about a point other than the origin, you most likely will need to shift point of interest to origin, rotate, and shift back to point of interest.

Comment: Do you mean a substitution to shift the axes?

Comment: Precisely! Could be simpler than rotating everything, tracking your now rotated point of interest and shifting back

Comment: So to rotate around $(a,b)$ I would use the substitutions $x=u-a$ and $y=v-b$?

Comment: Correct you would make the following subs: $x=u-a$ and $y=v-b$, perform the rotation in the way you mention above (which is correct) and then shift back

Answer (score 1):

You cannot eliminate one variable as the angle that the the function makes at a point is dependent on both x and y.

What you want to look at is called a rotation matrix. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

When you rotate a function about a point, you are causing a series of rotations about various axis. See the "In three dimensions" section of the Wikipedia article linked above, and pay attention to the "Rotation matrix from axis and angle" subsection. You can continue multiplying a function by rotation matrices to get your desired result.